# How to pass typedDict as arguments in Python FastAPI?

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, python-typing, typing

I am working on this simple FastAPI example and I would like to replace the `read_books` arguments with an equivalent `TypedDict`, like the commented line.
Is it possible?

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Query
from typing import Optional, TypedDict

# would like to define model for query parameter in separeted object
class GetModel(TypedDict):
    test: Optional[str]

query_param =  GetModel(test=Query('default value', max_length=10, title='titulo', description="description 123", regex="^[a-z]+"))


app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/books")
def read_books(test: Optional[str] = Query('default value', max_length=10, title='titulo', description="description 123", regex="^[a-z]+")):
#def read_books(query_param):
    """
    comentario do endpoint
    """
    results = {"books": [{"book_name": "The Great Hunt"}, {"book_name": "The Dragon Reborn"}]}

    if test:
        results.update({"test": {"name":test}})
    
    return results
```

Comment: Why don't you get the test from JSON body? I mean, your input is object; so why are you trying to get that object as query parameter?